# Precision and Recall for highly-imbalanced data

Tags: unbalanced-classes, metric

I have an imbalanced data with binary label where there are only 4% positive labels among all examples. I want to evaluate my model on the dataset, and I wonder what is the best way (best metric) to evaluate it.

My model produces predicted probabilities in $[0, 1]$ and it gives prediction in $\{0, 1\}$ by thresholding, and 0.5 is not the *best* threshold since the label is imbalanced. When I plot acc, precision, recall, and f1 score with thresholds from 0.01 to 0.99, I got the following graph:

[image]

For me, recall (sensitivity) is the most important metric. However, I can make it very high (>0.95) by simply set threshold as small as possible, which make the model to predict almost every example as negative. (Obviously, this makes precision super low). I can use f1, AUROC, or AUPRC, which mitigates such thresholding issues, but I wonder if there's a better way to evaluate *recall* in a reasonable way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think that AUPRC is a good way to go -- it essentially measures precision as a function of recall at varying thresholds -- but since you've mentioned that already, there's one more thing you can consider -- [**the F-beta measure**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score).

This builds directly off of F1-score. As you know, F1 is given by

$$F_1 = \frac{2P\cdot R}{P+R}$$

where $P$ is precision and $R$ is recall. What if you want to control the "balance" between precision and recall in this metric? That's where the **F-beta measure** comes in, which takes a positive scalar parameter $\beta$ as follows:

$$F_\beta = (1 + \beta^2) \frac{P \cdot R}{\beta^2 \cdot P + R}.$$

If you want to make recall matter more, make $\beta$ larger. $\beta=2$ is usually a good start, though this will need to be tuned experimentally. This should be sufficient for your purposes; I think it's important as well to remember that metrics are heavily task-dependent (which you see to be thinking about), so it's okay to try a few different metrics to see which one communicates your "point" most effectively.

If you're curious about why this metric weighs recall/precision more heavily depending on the setting of $\beta$, I've included an explanation below.

#### Extra Details (Why Does This Work)

Simplifying in terms of false/true positives/negatives, we can rewrite this as
$$F_\beta = (1 + \beta^2) \frac{\frac{TP}{TP + FP} \cdot \frac{TP}{TP + FN}}{\beta^2 \cdot \frac{TP}{TP + FP} +\frac{TP}{TP + FN}}$$
$$= (1 + \beta^2) \frac{\frac{TP}{(TP + FP)(TP + FN)}}{\beta^2 \cdot \frac{1}{TP + FP} +\frac{1}{TP + FN}}$$
$$= (1 + \beta^2) \frac{\frac{TP}{(TP + FP)(TP + FN)}}{\beta^2 \cdot \frac{TP + FN}{(TP + FP)(TP + FN)} +\frac{TP + FP}{(TP + FP)(TP + FN)}}$$
$$= \frac{(1 + \beta^2)\cdot TP}{\beta^2 (TP + FN) +TP + FP}$$
$$= \frac{(1 + \beta^2)\cdot TP}{(1 + \beta^2) \cdot TP + \beta^2 \cdot FN + FP}.$$

Thus, you can observe the influence of $\beta^2$ as a "weighing" term in the denominator of this metric. Specifically, the $FN$ term is multiplied by $\beta^2$; hence, increasing $\beta$ increases the influence/penalty that Type II Errors incur -- which is **consistent with recall being weighted higher.** Conversely, you can see how decreasing $\beta^2$ would result in a metric that puts more importance on precision. How $\beta$ corresponds to weighing recall $\beta$ times more heavily than precision is further explorer [in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/379474/263918)